# How can I stop SQL Server password recovery tools from resetting or restoring login password?

Tags: sql-server

There are many tools that can reset SQL Server login passwords and replace it with a new password, so anyone who has access to the server can do that and reset system administrator password and have full access to the server.

Is there anyway to stop that?

Or put another layer of security after login?

Comment: What is your question here exactly? The above is just one long statement without any grammar, making it very difficult to even understand what you're saying. To answer the question in your title: You can't stop a tool doing what it's designed to if it has permissions to do so. If you want to stop the tool, revoke the permissions of the Login it's using. HOw do you stop

Comment: Control physical/remote access to the server?

Comment: No, there are no such tools. Not unless some DBA *explicitly* weakens security, lockout policies, uses SQL logins instead of Windows accounts and quite a few more steps. Said DBA will probably have to explicitly provide physical access to the database server **and** shut down the server to allow any "recovery" tool to read the database files

Comment: The only people who would be able to reset an administrator password via SQL itself are those whose accounts also have system administrator privileges. If you don't trust those people not to do such a destructive act, then don't give them these privileges. Furthermore, make it a condition of granting those privileges that any unauthorized change such as the one you're describing would be punishable with disciplinary action. As regards any other hacking type tools, in order to succeed they would need other privileged access to the server, which also should not be granted except to trusted DBAs

Comment: This isn't a good question, more like a reaction to FUD, either from a tool vendor or a "security consultant". How is any tool going to crack the *DBA's Windows account* without access to the domain controller itself? How is any tool going to "recover" a password without physical access to the database files themselves? How is that tool going to *read* those files when they are locked by the SQL Server service?

Comment: A *legitimate* concern would be how to defend against physical theft of the disks or files. That's what encryption is for. Another legitimate concern would be protecting the data over the network. That's the job of HTTPS. Yet another legitimate concern would be preventing even DBAs from reading sensitive data. Again, encryption, specifically the AlwaysEncrypted feature. How to prevent a hacker from accessing the system through an application? Don't use `sa` as the application's user account. Only use accounts with limited access

Comment: Tool like SQL server login password recovery just need anyone has access to the server machine itself any user can stop the SQL server service and just use this tool to reset password in Master.MDF database file after that he can start the SQL server service and login with the password he just reset

Comment: This tool is example of what I'm talking about https://www.systoolsgroup.com/sql-password-recovery.html

Comment: "anyone has access to the server machine itself " ...this should be a very small group of trusted DBAs / sysadmins only. If they go around hacking / changing passwords without consent then you have to discipline or sack them. so apart from the people above who have legitimate reasons for accessing the server, who else has access to your server, and why???

Comment: Backup person , a database owner

Comment: I want to stop these tools anyway who is the person has access to the server itself or having another layer of security for sysadmin

Comment: Why would a database owner have access to the server other than via SQL itself? That seems unnecessary. And a backup person is a sysadmin...they should be trusted. If you don't trust them..why? Backup should be largely automated anyway... do these people actually need physical access most of the time? Maybe grant it only when actually needed, via an auditable process. I think you have a cultural issue, not a technical one

Comment: P.s if it was easy to stop these tools, I doubt people would be selling them, and I would expect that the solution would be available online already, instead of a queue of people here telling you you're going down the wrong road. What you need to do is: sort out who does and doesn't actually need access to your server, lock it down as much as possible, make the granting of (temporary or permanent) permissions an auditable procedure, and make clear the punishment for misbehaviour - if necessary, make people sign a form to agree to the terms, if it's not already in their contract.

Answer (score 1):

It is *by design* that a Windows Administrator can always stop SQL Server, restart it in single-user mode and connect as a sysadmin.  There's no way to change that.

See [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-2017)

> Or put another layer of security after login?

You can encrypt data on the server using keys that are not stored on the server, or available to the server administrators using [AlwaysEncrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017).